# Problemas con scripts

Tags: python, script

Necesito que mi código cree un archivo de texto en donde se encuentren escritas la cantidad de letras que contiene cada línea, pero cada cantidad en una línea distinta.
Esto es lo que tengo hecho

```
import sys
infilename = sys.argv[1]
outfilename = sys.argv[2]
 
infile = open(infilename)
outfile = open(outfilename, 'w')
charct = 0

for line in infile:
    charct = charct + len(line.strip("\n"))
    outfile.write(str(charct))
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Cabe destacar que es un curso básico de Python, por lo cual solo vi diccionarios, listas, csv, tuplas, y poco más.

Comment: `outfile.write("\n".join([len(line.strip()) for line in infile]))`

Comment: Solo te falta añadir el retorno de carro en el fichero de salida: `outfile.write(str(charct)+"\n")`, por ejemplo, o mejor aún `outfile.write("{}\n".format(charct))`. O si tienes una versión moderna de python `outfile.write(f"{charct}\n")`

Comment: Muchas gracias!